# MQTT Connection accepeted but not publishing

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, gsm

I'm working with Raspberry pi and GSM module Sim800, trying to send data through MQTT and python. When the MQTT connect packet is send, its getting back the conack \x30\x02\x00\x00, that means connection accepted, but after trying to send de publish packet, the subscriber is getting no answer.

I tried to change the Qos to 1, and sending the packet several times but not getting any puback.

This is the code

```
import serial
import time
from clibs.gsm import sim

def SendConnectPacket():
    print("Starting MQTT Connect Packet")
    simcard.AT("AT+CIPSEND")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(simcard.read(">", None))
    simcard.write(b'\x10\x32\x00\x04\x4D\x51\x54\x54\x04\xC2\x00\x3C\x00\x06\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x00\x16\x73\x65\x72\x67\x69\x6F\x2E\x76\x61\x67\x35\x38\x40\x67\x6D\x61\x69\x6C\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x00\x06\x34\x31\x30\x39\x39\x32' + chr(26).encode())   
    print("MQTT Connect Packet sent")

def SendPublishPacket():#msg
    print("start publish packet")
    simcard.AT("AT+CIPSEND")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(simcard.read(">", None))
    simcard.write(b'\x32\x23\x00\x1A\x73\x65\x72\x67\x69\x6F\x2E\x76\x61\x67\x35\x38\x40\x67\x6D\x61\x69\x6C\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x74\x72\x79\x00\x01\x48\x45\x4C\x4C\x4F' + chr(26).encode())

commandSent = False
atflag = 0
msgflag = 0
count = 0

simcard = sim()

while True:
    if atflag == -1:
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Putting GSM module to sleep... ")
            simcard.AT("AT+CFUN=0")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            answer = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if answer == 1:
                break
                
    elif atflag == 0:            
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Disabling Echo...")
            simcard.AT("ATE0&W")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1
    elif atflag == 1:            
        expecteda1 = "Call Ready"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Waking up GSM Module...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CFUN=1")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 2:            
        expecteda1 = "SHUT"
        expecteda2 = "OK"
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Closing previous GPRS...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CIPSHUT")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 3:            
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Configuring single ip connection...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CIPMUX=0")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 4:            
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Getting data from network manually...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CIPRXGET=1")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 5:            
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("GPRS Service's status...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CGATT=1")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 6:            
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Setting APN...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CSTT=" + APN)
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 7:            
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Bring up wireless connection...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CIICR")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 8:            
        expecteda1 = "."
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Getting local ip adress...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CIFSR")
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1
            elif acheck == 2:
                commandSent = False
                print("Not connected")

    elif atflag == 9:
        TCP_DIR = '"TCP","' + MQTTHOST + '","' + MQTTPort + '"'            
        expecteda1 = "CONNECT"
        expecteda2 = "OK"
        if commandSent == False:
            print("Startup connection...")
            simcard.AT("AT+CIPSTART=" + TCP_DIR)
            commandSent = True
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    
    elif atflag == 10 and msgflag == 0:
        expecteda1 = "SEND"
        expecteda2 = "OK"
        if commandSent == False:
            SendConnectPacket()
            print("Connect Packet sent")
            commandSent = True
            
        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 11:
        simcard.AT("AT+CIPRXGET=2,1024")
        expecteda1 = "x02"
        expecteda2 = None
        time.sleep(2)
        acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
        msgflag=1
        #    if acheck == 1:
        #        commandSent = False
        #        break

        atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 12:
        expecteda1 = "OK"
        expecteda2 = None
        if commandSent == False:
            SendPublishPacket()
            print("Publish Packet sent")
            commandSent = True

        else:
            acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
            if acheck == 1:
                commandSent = False
                atflag += 1

    elif atflag == 13:
        simcard.AT("AT+CIPRXGET=2,1024")
        expecteda1 = "x02"
        expecteda2 = None
        time.sleep(2)
        acheck = simcard.check(expecteda1, expecteda2)
        count+=1
        atflag = 12
        time.sleep(1)
        if count == 5:
            atflag = -1
            commandSent = False
```

Comment: Nowhere in this code is there a publish packet call?!?  You define the function to publish a packet, but never call it in any of your "steps"....at least not that my browser FIND function could find.  Tough to help a publish issue where there isn't one to look at ;)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the SendSuscribepacket for SendPublishPacket, i just edited the code, but even when I call the publish function is not giving results.